# Sql - get previous order which uses the item

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I have the following table

**order_item**

```
   order_id|   item_id
    --------------------------------
    213    |    3
    215    |    3
    244    |    2
    299    |    3
    400    |    3
```

**User input:** `item_id`  and `order_id` eg: `3 & 299` respectively in the above example.

**Requirement:** I need to find immediate last order which sold the item with item_id `3`. ( 215 order_id in this case)

Because input(order_id , item_id) is (299 , 3). From the table the recent past order which has sold item 3 is `order_id` 215 so, i need to return the (215, 3) row to the user.

I tried the following and I know it is wrong as i do not know how to get the above information.

```
select (select oi.item_id from order_item oi where oi.order_id < order_id and rownum =1) 
from order_item where order_id = 299 and item_id = 3
```

Comment: Please clarify your requirement. Not sure what you want.

Comment: @Tarik Editted the question. Please have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do:

```
select max(order_id) from order_item where  order_id <299 and item_id =3
```

Answer (score 1):

try this 
Oracle

```
 select order_id,item_id
       from order_item 
       where order_id <299 and item_id = 3 
       and rownum = 1
       order by order_id desc
```

SQL Server

```
select top 1 * 
   from order_item 
   where order_id <299 and item_id = 3 
   order by order_id desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this query ?

```
select max(order_id) from order_item where  order_id < ( 
select order_id from order_item where  order_id = 299 and item_id = 3  ) and item_id = 3;
```

Comment: You are right, i didn't realize order id is the key column here.